# Matlab, Matrix operation

Tags: performance, matlab, indexing

I have for example matrix a of indexes of other matrix A with size 50*50.

```
 2    21     1
 2    41     1
 2    47     1
 2    50     1
```

I want in each step to multiply for example for row 1

A(2,21)*A(21,1)
for row 2

A(2,41)*A(41,1)
.
.
.

so, I use this code

```
for i=1:nrow
c=ncol;
   if c~=1
   mul(i)=mul(i)*A(a(i,c-1),a(i,c));
   c=c-1;
   end
end
```

Is there any more efficient code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `sub2ind` and `prod`

```
mul=prod(A(sub2ind(size(A),a(:,1:end-1), a(:,2:end))),2);
```

Comment: I think this one is the winner

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia What about the answer if a has more than 2 columns and each time has different column size?

Comment: @Fatime Then it won't be a matrix. You need to represent it as a cell array.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your index matrix I, try something like this:
`mul = A(I(:,1),I(:,2)) * A(I(:,2),I(:,3))` and see if matlab can optimize it for you.
I'm rather rusty in matlab notation, so please excuse if the statement just plain out doesn't work.

EDIT: I think I don't fully understand what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A general one liner: `A(sub2ind(size(A), I(:, 1), I(:, 2))).*A(sub2ind(size(A), I(:, 2), I(:, 3)))`

For example:

```
 I= [2    5     1;
 2    4     1;
 2    3     1;
 2    1     1]

 A= rand(5, 5)


A(sub2ind(size(A), I(:, 1), I(:, 2))).*A(sub2ind(size(A), I(:, 2), I(:, 3)))
```